# Yii2 several application instances

Tags: php, apache, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I need several instances of a yii2 basic application running on the same code but using different config (database, params etc.)

For example

- http://myhost/url1/ - will load - /var/www/html/fw/config_1
- http://myhost/url2/ - will load - /var/www/html/fw/config_2

The entire framework including MVC remains the same. Currently, I have copied the entire structure but it's harder to maintain the application code this way.

I have tried setting up Aliases in the Apache config and requiring the config files based on the requested `$_SERVER` variable containing the URL, that sort of worked, except it caused routing problems inside the instances.

What would be the best & simplest practice here? Perhaps switching to yii2 advance application?

Comment: basically, you are trying to run different apps if i am not wrong, this is similar to the `yii2-advanced-app` where we have a `frontend`, `backend` and `console` and if required and `api` app also?

Comment: No. Same app, different instances each with a seperated DB.

Comment: okay then why don't you go for a modular structure where you could assign separate db in config, see [**`HERE`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/193/a-simple-class-to-use-a-different-db-for-a-module/) a simple module to use a separate database

Comment: The entire config is different (different params), not just the database. Also the separated instance should be accessed by a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using the Advanced application template rather than basic which works great for this purpose.

I use the `common` structure to hold most of the framework files that are used by several different app instances.